# Handling buttons deep in the compose hierarchy to switch views

Tags: kotlin, event-handling, android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application

What's the recommended way of handling button clicks in the compose hierarchy? I've got a list with items that have an edit-button next to them. When the user hits the button, the application should change the view to an editor for that item.

I guess I could pass the click handler function down through each composable, but this doesn't seem to be right as other composables would just relay it to deeper ones.

Is there an established *pattern* for such cases?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App() {
    
    var isBrowsing = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    if (isBrowsing)    
        Browser() // <-- somewhere inside there is the "Edit" button
    } else {
        Editor() // <-- somewhere inside there is the "Exit" button
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this section in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#deciding) about [`CompositionLocal`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal). It aims to make certain values available down the whole Composable hierarchy without the need to explicitly pass those values down with each Composable.

In the samples, this is primarily used for variables that are related to theming. But you can adapt it to work with a callback function instead. However, please be aware that I am not sure whether this is a recommended approach:

First, place this variable somewhere outside of a Composable function:

```
val EditorCallback = compositionLocalOf<(Boolean) -> Unit> {}
```

Then add this code to your Composables:

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    
    var isBrowsing by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    CompositionLocalProvider(EditorCallback provides { edit -> isBrowsing = !edit}) {
        if (isBrowsing)    
            Browser()
        } else {
            Editor()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
Editor() {
    var editorCallback = EditorCallback.current
    Button(onClick = { editorCallback(true) }) {
        Text(text = "EDIT")
    }
}
```

---

The safer approach would be inversion of control. Create a ViewModel that holds a Boolean, and insert this ViewModel into the deeply nested Composable as well as the top-level Composable like this:

```
@Composable
fun App(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {
    
    if (myViewModel.isBrowsing)    
        Browser() // <-- somewhere inside there is the "Edit" button
    } else {
        Editor() // <-- somewhere inside there is the "Exit" button
    }
    
}

@Composable
Editor(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Button(onClick = { myViewModel.isBrowsing = true }) {
        Text(text = "EDIT")
    }
}
```

---

Besides those suggestions, I think it really is okay in Compose to have a quite verbose number of parameters that are passed around. At the end, this improves testability of individual Composables.

Comment: `CompositonLocal` sounds promising, however, it doesn't seem to like to be used this way because of this: `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`. I started with a model, but I stopped as there were too many levels I had to pass it around and some components didn't require anything of it. No I wonder whether there is a trick to create a fake composobale context to call that lambda?

Comment: LOL it works when I put this line above the `Button`: `var setter = LocalScreen.current`. Then I can call `setter(true)` from inside `onClick`. Do you think this might hurt performance? Using `remember` is also no allowed as its lambda isn't a @Composable.

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that it works :D Thanks for trying out. I edited my answer and moved the code above the Button.

Comment: I can't judge the performance aspect, but in general, this is using the normal `CompositionLocal`, only with a function type. I would not know why this would be a problem in performance compared to passing other types.